# Netlogo : Issue with clipping to a GIS vector

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm trying to clip an input raster file to an input vector polygon shapefile in Netlogo. I'm using the GIS extension and the gis:intersecting primitive.

What I'm trying to get is the area of the raster INSIDE the vector polygon but which excludes the polygon itself. However, as far as I can tell gis:intersecting doesn't do this. It includes the pixels which are co-located with the polygon line.

Yes, I could clip the rasters to the vector outside Netlogo in some GIS software. It's just quicker and cleaner to do so inside.

Is there an obvious solution to this that I'm missing? Am I using the wrong command? I'm still pretty new to Netlogo so I've got lots to learn.

```
ask patches gis:intersecting my_polygon_extent
  [set fenced_area? true set pcolor green]
```

Thanks for any pointers